# java multi-dimensional array split

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

I have a multidimensional array:

```
// nums[3][0]
String[][] nums = new String[3][0];
nums = {{32,123,74},{543,98,5},{96,24,23},{12,98,56}}
```

Tha output of `System.out.println(nums[0][0])` is `32, 123, 74`
I want to split the columns, so the output should be like this:

```
System.out.println(nums[0][0]); // Output: 32
System.out.println(nums[1][2]); // Output: 5
```

I tried `nums[0][0] = nums[0][0].split(",");` but there was an error

I'm stuck I couldn't do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! People will be more inclined to help you if you show us what you've already tried, even if it doesn't work. Then we can help guide you in the right direction. If we simply solve your problem for you, you won't have actually learned anything.

Comment: The code does not compile. You cannot use integers in a String array. Your result array is the same as the starting one.

Comment: can you tell me what diffirence between `{{32,123,74},{543,98,5},{96,24,23},{12,98,56}}` and `{{32,123,74},{543,98,5},{96,24,23},{12,98,56}}`?

Comment: There are two code blocks and both have the same array in them. Also, Alessandro's point, you can't have integer for String ... have you tried compiling your code at all ? Maybe use some IDE like eclipse (http://eclipse.org) or netbeans (http://netbeans.org) to make your life easier if you are starting to write cod.e

Comment: This question has been asked before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I've understood correctly what you wanted to ask.

First of all as it was already mentioned you can't store integers in String array.

Secondly, in Java two-dimensional array is actually the array of arrays. So when you declare `int[][] nums = int[4][3]` you create an `int[]` array `nums` that has four elemets and each of these elements is another `int[]` array of length 3. So if you imagine that your two-dimentional array is kind of matrix you can easily retreive it's "rows" as elements of `nums` array.

```java
int[][] nums = {{32, 123, 74}, {543, 98, 5}, {96, 24, 23}, {12, 98, 56}};

int[] rowOne = nums[0];     // {32, 123, 74}
int[] rowTwo = nums[1];     // {543, 98, 5}
int[] rowThree = nums[2];   // {96, 24, 23}
int[] rowFour = nums[3];    // {12, 98, 56}
```

Getting "columns" is a little bit trickier a long as they just don't exist in terms of java. But you still can do this as follows:

```java
int[] columnOne = new int[nums.length];
for (int i = 0; i < columnOne.length; i++) {
  columnOne[i] = nums[i][0]; // {32, 543, 96, 12}
}

int[] columnTwo = new int[nums.length];
for (int i = 0; i < columnTwo.length; i++) {
  columnTwo[i] = nums[i][1]; // {123, 98, 24, 98}
}

int[] columnThree = new int[nums.length];
for (int i = 0; i < columnThree.length; i++) {
  columnThree[i] = nums[i][2]; // {74, 5, 23, 56}
}
```